# Is the image of $S=\big\{(a,b,c,d)\in\Bbb Z^4\,|\, ad-bc=1 \big\}$, via the projection map $p:\Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R^4/2\pi\Bbb Z^4$, dense?

Tags: general-topology, number-theory

I recently came across a problem that I cannot find a solution to. Let $\Bbb R^4$ be the $4-$dimensional Euclidean space as usual and let $2\pi\Bbb Z^4$ be a lattice inside $\Bbb R^4$. Then, consider the quotient space $\Bbb R^4/ 2\pi\Bbb Z^4$ which is homeomorphic to $\big(\Bbb S^1\big)^4$ and let $p:\Bbb R^4 \to \big(\Bbb S^1\big)^4$ define the projection to the quotient.

Consider now the set $S=\big\{(a,b,c,d)\in\Bbb Z^4\,|\, ad-bc=1 \big\}\subset \Bbb R^4.$ This is clearly a discrete subset of $\Bbb R^4$.

> **Question:**  Let $p(S)$ be the image of $S$ via the projection map. 
>   What can we say about $p(S)$? Is it a dense subset of $\big(\Bbb S^1\big)^4$?

If one drops the condition $ad-bc=1$, then $S=\Bbb Z^4$ and the answer of the previous question turns out affirmative since we are taking the quotient by $2\pi\Bbb Z^4$. However, with that condition, the subset $S$ is less than $\Bbb Z^4$. In fact, for any given pair of integers $(b,c)\in \Bbb Z^2$, the condition imposes $$ad=1+bc$$ and there are only a finite number of pairs $(a,d)\in \Bbb Z^2$ satisfying the equation above. Hence, my personal feeling is that the image of $S$ via $p$ may be not dense in $\big(\Bbb S^1\big)^4$.

I tried to argue by contradiction but, unfortunately, my attempt did not work. Have you any ideas or suggestions? Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't agree with your intuition. Remember, denseness means that for every matrix $2\times 2$ matrix with entries in $[0,2\pi)$, we can "wiggle it" a bit and find a matrix in $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ that matches the first matrix mod $2\pi$. But this is not surprising, since we we have so much freedom: the small wiggle is a continuous freedom of small magnitude, and the mod $2\pi$ condition is a discrete freedom of large magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an outline to a proof that the image is dense. Consider $(a,b,c,d) = ((x+1)\cdot\frac{p}{q}, (x-1)\cdot\frac{q}{p}, x\cdot\frac{r}{s}, x\cdot\frac{s}{r}),$ for coprime $p,q,r,s$ and suitable $x \pmod {pqrs}$ (which exists by the Chinese Remainder Theorem). This yields periodic points on a line in 4-dimensional space; taking the image of these points yields a dense subset of the image of the line in $2\pi \mathbb{Z}^4$. However, note that the gradients of the line is given by the ratio of coprime $p,q,r,s$ which can approximate any ratio arbitrarily well, and therefore the lines in $2\pi \mathbb{Z}^4$ are also dense. Therefore we conclude that the image of $S$ is dense.